# Output recordset from dynamic SQL or another stored procedure saved in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Since Transact-SQL does not allow for construction like `select * from exec ..`,
sometimes it is very time consuming when we have to call dynamic query or other stored procedure and save output records in the table. We have to look for  column names, data types and length in proper order etc. etc.

I prepared the procedure which is doing it automatically: just call `UDP_DynSQLToTable` with code to execute and table name to store output. 
Procedure also works with temporary tables, but local temp tables have to be created before call, with any structure (will be altered by procedure).

Example of usage:

```
create table #CurrentUsers (dummy_field bit)

exec UDP_DynSQLToTable N'sp_who', '#CurrentUsers' 

if exists (select 1 from #CurrentUsers where name='MyBoss') ...
```

I did not test it so intensively, so use it on you own responsibility and any comments or improvements are welcome.

Regards

```
create procedure UDP_DynSQLToTable
    @sqlcode nvarchar(max),
    @table nvarchar(2048),
    @overwrite bit = 0
as
begin

set nocount on 

/*  
    exec dbo.UDP_DynSQLToTable 'sp_who', 'myTable', 1 select * from myTable drop table myTable
*/

declare 
    @cmd nvarchar(max)='',
    @dropcols nvarchar(max)='',
    @createsql nvarchar(max),
    @fieldList nvarchar(max),
    @altersql nvarchar(max),
    @sqltable nvarchar(max)

select @table=ltrim(rtrim(isnull(@table,'')))


begin try

if len(@table)=0
begin
    print object_name(@@procid)+': missing table name'
    return 
end 

if left(@table,1)='[' and right(@table,1)=']'
    select 
        @sqltable=@table,
        @table=substring(@table,2,len(@table)-2)
else 
    select @sqltable='['+@table+']'

if (left(@table,1)='#' and left(@table,2)!='##')
begin
    if object_id('tempdb..'+@table) is null
    begin
        print object_name(@@procid)+': #table '+@table+' must be created (any structure) before call this proc'
        return -4
    end 
    else 
    begin
        select @cmd = 'if (select count(*) from '+@sqltable+') > 0 delete from '+@sqltable
        exec sp_executesql @cmd
        if not exists (select name from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id=object_id('tempdb..'+@table) and name='dummy___field')
        begin
            select @cmd = 'alter table '+@sqltable+' add dummy___field bit'
            exec sp_executesql @cmd
        end 
        if exists (select name from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id=object_id('tempdb..'+@table) and name!='dummy___field')
        begin
            select @dropcols = 'alter table '+@sqltable+' drop column '
            select @dropcols = @dropcols+name+','
            from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id=object_id('tempdb..'+@table) and name!='dummy___field'
            select @dropcols=left(@dropcols,len(@dropcols)-1)
            exec sp_executesql @dropcols
        end 
    end 
end 
else if  OBJECT_ID(case when left(@table,2)='##'then 'tempdb.' else '' end +@table) is not null
begin
    if @overwrite=0
    begin
        print object_name(@@procid)+': object '+@table+' already exists'
        return -2
    end 
    else 
    begin
        select @cmd = 'drop table '+@sqltable 
        exec sp_executesql @cmd
    end
end 

select @createsql = 'create table '+@sqltable+' ('+char(13)
select @fieldList = ''
select @altersql  = 'alter table '+@sqltable+' add '


select 
    @createsql=@createsql+char(9)+isnull(name,'column_'+convert(nvarchar,column_ordinal))+' '+system_type_name+' '+
        case when isnull(is_identity_column,0)=1 then 'IDENTITY ' else '' end +
        case when isnull(is_part_of_unique_key,0)=1 then 'UNIQUE ' else '' end+
        case when isnull(is_nullable,1)=0 then 'NOT NULL ' else '' end +','+char(13),
    @fieldList=@fieldList+name+',',
    @altersql=@altersql++char(9)+isnull(name,'column_'+convert(nvarchar,column_ordinal))+' '+system_type_name+' '+
        case when isnull(is_identity_column,0)=1 then 'IDENTITY ' else '' end +
        case when isnull(is_part_of_unique_key,0)=1 then 'UNIQUE ' else '' end+
        case when isnull(is_nullable,1)=0 then 'NOT NULL ' else '' end +','+char(13)
from 
(
select top 1000000 
    column_ordinal, name, system_type_name, is_identity_column, is_nullable, is_part_of_unique_key
from  
    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sqlcode, null, null)  order by column_ordinal
) a 

print @createsql

select @altersql=left(@altersql,len(@altersql)-2)
select @createsql=left(@createsql,len(@createsql)-2)+char(13)+char(9)+')'
select @fieldList=left(@fieldlist,len(@fieldlist)-1)

if left(@table,2)='##' or left(@table,1)!='#'
    exec sp_executesql @createsql 
else 
begin
    exec sp_executesql @altersql
    select @cmd = 'alter table '+@sqltable+' drop column dummy___field'
    exec sp_executesql @cmd
end 

select @cmd = 'insert into '+@sqltable+' ('+@fieldList+')  exec sp_executesql N'+''''+@sqlcode+''''

exec sp_executesql @cmd
end try 
begin catch
    declare @m nvarchar(max)=object_name(@@procid)+' error: '+error_message()+char(13)+'Line '+convert(nvarchar,ERROR_LINE())
    raiserror(@m,1,1)
end catch end
```

Comment: I was.. but without create :-)

Comment: This isn't a question.   If you're looking for feedback on your code, you should post it on codereview.stackexchange.com.   This post is off-topic for Stack Overflow.